# OpCode compression, decompression and encoding differences?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I have a simple `.asm` file:

```
    BITS 64

        SECTION .text
        global main

    main:
        mov rax, 0x2a     ; 42
```

The `mov` statement is really all that compiles to machine code using the following command line:

> nasm.exe -o load_rax.bin -f bin load_rax.asm

...and the resulting binary output is:

> `0xb8 0x2a 0x00 0x00 0x00`

When I compile the same `mov` instruction through [this Online x86 / x64 Assembler and Disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm), I get something completely different:

> `0x48 0xc7 0xc0 0x2a 0x00 0x00 0x00`

Am I doing something wrong with compiling via NASM? I understand that there could be op-code compression going on and if that is the case then I'd prefer to be able to handle that but then I need to know if the instructions have been compressed, how to tell and what algorithm was used.

I am working only in 64-bit.

Any ideas on why these binaries are different would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Sometimes there's multiple different ways of encoding the same instruction, in that case the assembler (should) pick the smallest encoding, and if there multiple shortest encodings then the choice is arbitrary.  In some cases there are shorter instructions that do the exact same thing as a given (but different) instruction and an assemblers will often substitute the shorter one instead as an optimization. There's no "opcode compression" going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b8 2a 00 00 00` is an instance of `mov r32, imm32`,
`48 c7 c0 2a 00 00 00` is an instance of `mov r/m64, imm32`

There is, I suppose, an argument to made that the longer encoding is "what you asked for", because it explicitly writes to the 64bit version of the register like you told it to. On the other hand, it is useless to encode it that way since writes to 32bit registers are zero-extended anyway, so NASMs encoding isn't wrong, it's just taking your code slightly less literally.

Comment: This is what doesn't make sense to me: `mov eax, 0x2a` compiles to `0x66 0xb8 0x2a 0x00 0x00 0x00`. Does the Intel IA-32 manual give op-code -> machine code conversion?

Comment: @IAbstract You're assembling in 16-bit mode (`BITS 16` is implied with `-f bin`) so it needs a operand size prefix `0x66` to make it a 32-bit instruction instead of a 16-bit one (`mov ax, 0x2a`).  In 32-bit and 64-bit mode its the other way around, and a operand size prefix is needed to make it a 16-bit operation.

Comment: Yep - 0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x2a
nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf stuff.s -o stuff.o

Comment: @IAbstract the manual has the encoding in the first column all across chapter 3 and some extra rules that you may need in chapter 2, appendix B is also useful. Beware of errors though.